# smalltalk returning string from block in VisualWorks

Tags: block, smalltalk, visualworks

I want to return the value, that was passed int to the block. If it's a number, everything works great, but If I put in a String or boolean value, I get a "Message not understand".

```
q := [ :a | a].
Transcript show: ((q value:'123') value) printString.
```

I thought everything is treated the same, so I'm confused. But I guess I'm just missing something.

edit: it seem to work under Pharo...

Comment: can you provide _which_ message is not understood?

Comment: Pharo implements Object>>value to answer self. As David said, VW does not do that by default, but it's a common extension.

Comment: Sorry for not posting that information. I'm new to VW and Smalltalk. So I didn't get that information. Now I know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message "value" isn't implemented for Object in VisualWorks.  Some applications add it in but it's not in the base class library.  In some versions of VisualWorks it slipped into the base class library and was later taken out.

If you write your code like this it will work:

```
q := [ :a | a].
Transcript show: (q value:'123') printString.
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the send of `#value`. It is not necessary for your example as you described it. `#value:` is sent to the Block, which returns the argument, as you wanted. You then send `#value` to the *argument*, which works in Pharo because it returns self and is essentially a non-op.

This fixes your error because, as I suspected and David verified, VisualWorks Strings DNU `#value`.

n.b. As Bob said, the key missing info in your question is "Which object DNU which message?" In general, the more specific you are about your errors, the better the answers can be.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me.

```
| q |
q := [ :a | a].
Transcript show: ((q value: true) value) printString.

| q |
q := [ :a | a].
Transcript show: ((q value: 123) value) printString.
```

If you have a DNU exception you will be able to see which object is receiving the message that is not understood. Post that information.

Comment: ByteString did not understand the message. Apparently not implemented, as the others told :)